# Support ArcGIS Enterprise + Portal across multiple domains

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise

I have an ArcGIS Enterprise + Portal environment where I would like to host content across two domains to two separate sets of users (domain1.com and domain2.com).  I would like to find any documentation (case studies, architectures, best practices, etc) that would help me architect a solution that minimizes data redundancy and prioritizes security.  Both systems are on Windows server using Active Directory (not Azure AD).

I would like to use Active Directory as the identity store.

Does this mean I need two environments for each domain or is there a recommended and tested way to support two domains on one cluster?